# tank Auth set_value undefined in register_form

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

I get the following error when click on sign up button.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function set_value() in C:\wamp\www\bdcom\www\application\views\auth\register_form.php on line 19

I am new to codeigniter framework.

following is the code in register_form.php

```
if ($success){
    echo '<div id=success>'.$success_message.'<div>';
}else {
    //show the form
$use_username = true;
if ($use_username) {
    $username = array(
        'name'  => 'username',
        'id'    => 'username',
        'value' => set_value('username'),

        'maxlength' => $this->config->item('username_max_length', 'tank_auth'),
        'size'  => 30,
    );
}
```

And this is how I load register.php in auth.php

```
$this->load->view('auth/register_form', $data);
```

Have loaded the form helper in autoloader as well. Stuck from 3 days tring to figure out what the problem is. Appreciate the help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if your autoload.php has the following, if not add them, its due to form helper not being loaded.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','html');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor of your controller write this:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

Comment: Have this also as well. Have searched for a day in stackoverflow and ellislabs. CI seems to working fine except for register user.